# Conteúdo carregado em uma DIV com rolagem automática barra rolagem

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Preciso da ajuda de vocês. Estou montando um sistema de chat, e como sou cabeça dura estou montando tudo na mão pra poder aprender. A questão é a seguinte, eu tenho uma página index.php e uma página chamada chat.php. Eu gostaria de saber como devo criar um script para que eu possa carregar o conteudo da página chat.php dentro de uma DIV na página index.php e fazer com que o scroll role automaticamente para baixo. Já tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```html
<script>
var tempo = window.setInterval(carrega, 5000);
function carrega()
{
$('#chat').load("chat.php");
}
</script>
```

Naturalmente, a barra de rolagem irá voltar para o topo ao fim do intervalo estipulado pelo setInterval, mesmo que desça manualmente para baixo. De que forma devo proceder para que ela fique sempre embaixo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$("#chat").load("chat.php");
$("#chat").animate({ scrollTop: $("#div").height() }, 1000);
```

Fonte http://www.codigosnaweb.com/forum/Rolagem-automatica-em-janela-de-CHAT-jQuery_3_9776.html

Comment: Excelente! Funcionou 100%. Obrigado!